# Override Property value in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-2.5

I need to override a property value given in my property file while loading my JBOSS Application server.

I tried out with below code overriding processProperties() method in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

My property file has this entry

**base.url="defaultUrl"**

```
public class CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
    return (originalValue != null) ? originalValue.trim() : originalValue;
}

@Override
protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties props)
        throws BeansException {
    super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);
    for (Enumeration names = props.propertyNames(); names.hasMoreElements();) {
        String key = (String) names.nextElement();
        props.put("base.url", getUpdatedUrl());
    }
}
```

}

I am injecting base.url value in a placeholder ${base.url} in application context.

How should I update the value of given property in run time. The above code always take the value in the property file not the updated value.

Comment: Did you registered your class as bean? (If you debug your code, is the snippet executed?)

Comment: yes it is executing and setting the value , but I get the base url as the one in the property file.

Comment: refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252864/how-to-extend-spring-by-configuring-spring-xml#)

Answer (score 0):

Blowing the dust off from this question. This can be done using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and adding a new property file (at the end of the list), where you put the properties you want to override. (The name/file path of the property file can contain an environment variable you pass at build time). Here's the javadoc of `PropertiesLoaderSupport#setLocations`:

> Note: Properties defined in later files will override properties
>   defined earlier files, in case of overlapping keys. Hence, make sure
>   that the most specific files are the last ones in the given list of
>   locations.

As of Spring 5.2 this was deprecated in favor of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:

> Specialization of PlaceholderConfigurerSupport that resolves ${...}
>   placeholders within bean definition property values and @Value
>   annotations against the current Spring Environment and its set of
>   PropertySources.

Some examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer)